# font awesome with Angular 2

Tags: angular, fonts

I started an NG2 app and wanna add font awesome.
I npm installed it with : npm install --save font-awesome angular2-font-awesome.
I added to project in systemjs.config.js:

```
map: {
  // our app is within the app folder
  app: 'app',

  // angular bundles
  '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
  '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
  '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
  '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
  '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
  '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
  '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
  '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',

  // other libraries
  'rxjs':                      'npm:rxjs',
  'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api/bundles/in-memory-web-api.umd.js',
  'angular2-fontawesome': 'node_modules/angular2-fontawesome'
},
// packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
packages: {
  app: {
    defaultExtension: 'js'
  },
  rxjs: {
    defaultExtension: 'js'
  },
  'angular2-fontawesome': { defaultExtension: 'js' }
}
```

and I added in app.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';
import { CorporateComponent }  from './corporate/corporate.component';
import { Angular2FontawesomeModule } from 'angular2-fontawesome/angular2-fontawesome'

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule , Angular2FontawesomeModule],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, CorporateComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Now I try to use it in my component:
I add in the html template:

```
<i class="fa fa-industry" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

But somehow I don't see it...
I followed the manual of npm: https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-fontawesome

Is there anything else that I might have forgotten ?

Thanks for any answer!

Comment: Have you downloaded their `font-awesome` fonts `(otf|eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)`?

Comment: please check the documentation, you have to use it like <fa [name]="industry"></fa>

Comment: and yes instead of using the ng2 plugin using the font awesome original link is a better option.

Answer (score 6):

if you wanna using FontAwesome css style in your app, just put css link to your index.html, you don't need `angular2-font-awesome`

`index.html`

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

if you using `angular2-font-awesome`

```
<i fa [name]="industry"></i>
<fa [name]="industry"></fa>
```

i think use cdn is better.

Comment: thanks, it's greate - I added the link <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"> as you suggested and it works.
The problem is why the other way with npm doesn't work...
and I guess that with angular 2 we have great ways to prevent us from  loading the js files in the index.

Comment: FontAwesome contain only css, why you need a bunch of code to use css class wrapper, i guess `angular2-font-awesome` only parse your input name, then apply template for you `<i fa [name]="industry"></i>
<fa [name]="industry"></fa>` -> `<i class="fa fa-industry"></i>`

Comment: from this section `https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-fontawesome#angular-cli` it's seem this lib need you put `css,fonts` of FontAwesome to your app, if not, it won't work. this lib only provide another way, instead coding a long css class name. and you missing css, fonts in your first config.

Comment: but i dont use angular-cli

Comment: this is example, this mean, you need add `css, fonts` and serve these file to use `angular2-font-awesome`

Comment: I added the font-awesome.css and the *.+(otf|eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)
in the index but it works only when I add the :
"http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" as you suggested....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135156/discussion-between-moshi-and-tiep-phan).

Answer (score 0):

Not much of effort is needed just include the [**script**](https://use.fontawesome.com/0bf64067d1.js) tag.

```
<div>
      <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
      <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
</div>
```

and my index.html contains script reference to the above script URL.

[image]

Get your script code by **[Registering Here](https://cdn.fontawesome.com/)**. You will receive a  mail from font-awesome as below [image]

**[LIVE DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/KP0LhjdgdsDXpJi4aF5H?p=preview)**

Comment: Hi
I wondered why should I add a link in the index page
and not use the font awesome just were needed just as 
any other module...
It's not the benefit of export/import ?
We shouldn't avoid of having links in the index.html ?

Comment: Nothing as such. when you add it using the ng2-fontawesome also it would be added to the index.html. So no much difference.

Comment: and what is the difference between adding the link:
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
or the cdn as you suggest ?

Comment: NO idea, as I tried the same it didnt work for me. just found an alternative :D

Comment: but you added the imports in the app.module.ts like I did , right ?

Comment: nothing as such I did. ! did you have a look at the plunker?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add it to your .angular-cli.json section 
 like this:

you may have it under a different name in your node_modules. try to go down the list in node_modules and see under what name it has been installed. The other thing I noticed is `npm install --save font-awesome angular-font-awesome`

```
`"styles": [
    "styles.css",
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
    "../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css",
    "../node_modules/npm-font-open-sans/open-sans.styl"


  ],
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this method:

Firstly install font awesome using command : `npm install --save font-awesome angular-font-awesome`

secondly, import it in your style.scss file with

```
$fa-font-path: "../node_modules/font-awesome/fonts";
@import "../node_modules/font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.scss";
```

or to your style.css file with

```
@import '~font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css';
```

command. The fonts are ready to use.

Now place your font in any html file. `<i class="fa facebook"></i>`

Answer (score 0):

If you're using **SCSS**, you can go with the following method:

```
npm install --save font-awesome
```

Then in the file **style.scss**

```
$fa-version: '4.7';
$fa-font-path: '../fonts';
@import '../node_modules/font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.scss';
```

**$fa-font-path** must be relative to font-awesome.scss.

**$fa-version** does not need to be defined, but if you check the file **node_modules/font-awesome/scss/_path.scss**, you'll notice the url's like:

```
...
src: url('#{$fa-font-path}/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=#{$fa-version}');
...
```