# md-sidenav preventing anchor tags from working

Tags: angular, angular-material2

Okay, so Angular 4, Angular Material 2, Node 8 (though problem existed with 6.x). Using md-sidenav with anchor tags as content. CSS isn't hitting them and clicking doesn't do anything. Checkout for open tags, tried switching mode to over, push, & side - problem persists. MdSidevnavModule is imported in my app module and works as expected otherwise. Tried changing the anchor tags to buttons - same issue. I apologize in advance if I'm missing something silly or missing info needed to diagnose. Thanks in advance.

```
<md-sidenav-container class="container mat-elevation-z12" 
color="primary">

<md-sidenav #sidenav mode="push" class="sidenav">
<div class="contact-container">
  <a href="#"><h1 id="call-to-action">Contact</h1></a>
  <a href="https://www.google.com">
    <i class="fa fa-linkedin-square fa-5x social-icon" id="linkedin" 
aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </a>
  <a href="https://www.google.com">
    <i class="fa fa-github-square fa-5x social-icon" id="github" aria-
hidden="true"></i>
  </a>
  <a href="https://www.google.com">
    <i class="fa fa-facebook-official fa-5x social-icon" id="facebook" 
aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </a>
  <a href="https://www.google.com">
    <i class="fa fa-twitter-square fa-5x social-icon" id="twitter" 
aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </a>
</div>
</md-sidenav>

<div class="sidenav-content">
  <h1 class="banner">Hey</h1>   
</div>

</md-sidenav-container>
```

Comment: Does the problem persist if you use a text instead of an icon within the anchor tag?

Comment: Unfortunately yes, any buttons or link, regardless of inner text/icon aren't clickable. There's also an interesting issue with the first "clickable" item being focused https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/3289, which may or may not have anything to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

No, it will not prevent it from working. The issue might be wrong `font awesome` icons.

My sample code

```
<md-sidenav-container class="example-container">
   <md-sidenav #sidenav class="example-sidenav">
    <a href="https://www.google.com">
       <i class="fa fa-facebook" id="twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </a>
    <a href="https://www.google.com">
      <i class="fa fa-google" id="twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </a>
  </md-sidenav>
</md-sidenav-container>
```

Note: Use this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42106818/font-awesome-with-angular-2/42107084#42107084) to get font-awesome

**[LIVE DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/SsCdY4tNOunlwojAFUnu?p=info)** illustrating anchor tag works inside `md-side-nav`

Comment: Hmm, yeah the focused element problem shows in that Plunker, but your icons are, in fact, clickable. I'm having the focus issue, but can't get anything clickable...

Comment: Can you create a plunker to reproduce

Answer (score 0):

My apologies - issue resolved. I knew it would be something silly *facepalm*

I had a z-index -1 on my sidenav (I don't remember why), which was preventing any clicks. Ugh.