# Fontawesome 5 with Angular 2+

Tags: angular, font-awesome-5, angular-fontawesome

I don't know how to include FontAwesome 5 to Angular 2+ app.
I found this package - https://www.npmjs.com/package/@fortawesome/fontawesome
Could you tell me where should I import this package?
Maybe in app.module.ts file?

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-include-font-awesome

Comment: Can you confirm if that works with font awrsome v5.x.x?

Comment: @j3hyde had mentioned that how to [add FontAwesome using CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48184079/include-fortawesome-fontawesome-to-angular-cli-project#answer-48192503) with Angular.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Font Awesome 5 with Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48027322/font-awesome-5-with-angular)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First: you need to install the packages:

```
$ npm i --save @fortawesome/fontawesome

$ npm i --save @fortawesome/fontawesome-free-solid
$ npm i --save @fortawesome/fontawesome-free-regular
$ npm i --save @fortawesome/fontawesome-free-brands
```

Then in your **app.component.ts** you add the imports:

```
import fontawesome from '@fortawesome/fontawesome';
import faTrashAlt from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free-regular/';
```

and in your **constuctor of the app.component** you add the icon to the fontawesome library:

```
fontawesome.library.add(faTrashAlt);
```

In the html page you just add the icon:

```
<i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i>
```

Link to fontawesome documentation:
https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/use-with-node-js#free

Comment: So I need to add the icons one by one? Can add all icons at once?

Comment: @Dimonina Yes you can - import { fas } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'; fontawesome.library.add(fas);

Answer (score 0):

you need to install the package:

```
npm install @fortawesome/fontawesome-free
```

then import all

```
import "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css";
```

or import separately, like that:

```
import "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/fontawesome.css";
import "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/solid.css";
```