# include library fontawesome Pro manually External in Angular 7

Tags: angular, font-awesome

How should I include libraries external to Angular? I want to include Fontawesome Pro in my project. But I do not know exactly where to put my library folder.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Include @fortawesome/fontawesome to angular-cli project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48184079/include-fortawesome-fontawesome-to-angular-cli-project)

Comment: no, i would like manually external include fontawesome Pro, i resolved here https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/setup/using-package-managers?fbclid=IwAR3ef_gIvsQsb7Kv0TIkAIJPxo-LAaltKMcsaiICpHfHXMOlPdijBSUnKDc

Answer (score 1):

You can use npm package,

```
npm install --save font-awesome angular-font-awesome
```

Import your root module,

```
import { AngularFontAwesomeModule } from 'angular-font-awesome';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    AngularFontAwesomeModule
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

If you are using Angular CLI, you need to add it to your `angular-cli.json` as other answer shown.

```
"styles": [
    "../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css"
]
```

Documentations are [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-font-awesome),

Answer (score 0):

you must install it with npm , for example `npm i font-awesome --save`

and add path to styles in angular.json file

`"styles":[
 "./node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css",
]`

Answer (score 0):

I would like to include manually. I believe it is possible to do this in the assets in Angular, however, as I needed the fontawesome Pro, I got it here: https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/setup/using-package- managers? fbclid = IwAR3ef_gIvsQsb7Kv0TIkAIJPxo-LAaltKMcsaiICpHfHXMOlPdijBSUnKDc